# Informations, features about PGP Desktop?

Tags: windows, pgp-desktop

I need *feature lists*, documentations about PGP Desktop!!

Can anyone post a good list, that what can it do?

Thank you!

Comment: Your first step for any feature request should be to visit the vendor's own page, with Stack Exchange as a follow up if you can't find specific information you need.

See Help Vampires: http://slash7.com/2006/12/22/vampires/

Answer (score 3):

[The PGP features page](https://pgp.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/822/~/pgp-desktop-feature-control) lists features in the following areas:

- General
- Licensing
- Messaging & Keys
- File & Disk
- WDE

Comment: I understand where the snark is coming from here (and I'm in total agreement) but I'm not sure this is a constructive answer as it currently stands.  Perhaps you should edit the snark out into a comment on the main question and leave the answery bits.

Comment: @Shinrai - you are right. Sorry.

Comment: @Rory - +1 for being reasonable. :)

Comment: @Shinrai - well, you were dead right. I've had a rough day, and was definitely a bit snarky and out of order. The OP didn't deserve it.

Comment: i wanted to say in _encryption_ :) ... can it encrypt partitions, of only full disks? could there be a way, that one partition of the hdd uses uses encrypted VolumeGroups, and one partition uses PGPDesktop to securelly store data&be bootalbe too? sry for the silly question :O

Comment: @johnny - yes, it can do both of those. you can have the entire disk encrypted, or a volume, or a partition, or a folder, or a file. Or combinations of all the above.